# Probability that the stapler is the one not working

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving, conditional-probability

I had three staplers in my drawer. I knew that one of them always worked, that one of them
never worked, and that the third one worked with probability $1/2$. But I did not know which was
which because they all looked the same. I wanted to establish which stapler was the one that
never worked. I took one stapler at random and tried it and it worked. Then I took another
stapler at random and tried it twice and both times it did not work. What is the probability
that the second stapler that I tried, which twice failed to work, is the one which never works?

Is the probability 1/2? since if the first stapler is:

1)Stapler which works(which probability of being taken out is 1/3)--> there's a 1/2 probability that the second stapler is the not working one. Then the probability of this case is P= (1/3)x(1/2)= 1/6

2)Stapler which works with 1/2(which probability of being taken out is 1/3)--> there's a 1 probability that the second stapler is not working. Then the probability of this case is P= (1/3)x1= 1/3

Hence by adding the 2 probabilities I yield P(stapler that's not working)= P(1st case)+ P(2nd case)= (1/6)+(1/3)= 1/2

Any recommended formulas maybe that you recommend I use and hints if this is wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify? Is it possible that the second stapler was the same as the first one or are you sure it was a different one?

Comment: Do you mean first and second case? First case-first stapler is the one 100% working.

Comment: where is the case of the first stapler works always, the second one was working with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and did not work for the two times(i.e. with probability $\frac{1}{4}$)

Comment: Seems like [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) should give you your answer. Try it where $A$ is the event that the second stapler is the always bad one, and $B$ is this particular attempt at using the staplers.

Comment: @ab123 why would I consider this? Isn't saying that the probability of taking out either of them is 1/2 enough?

Comment: @ThePoorJew because you "know" that the second one didn't work twice, so isn't it more likely that it's the one that doesn't work? You need the conditional probability of the second stapler being faulty when you "know" that it didn't work twice. Think that you used the second one a hundred times and it didn't work, then would you still think that there is a 50-50 chance of this stapler being faulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can apply [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) to solve this problem. We first need to find the scenarios in which we arrive at the outcome you observed. Either:

1. The first stapler always works and the second stapler never works;
2. The first stapler always works and the second stapler works half of the time, and this second stapler did not work twice;
3. The first stapler works half of the time, and it worked, and the second stapler never works.

We then have to divide the probability of either the first or the third scenario happening, by the probability of one of these scenarios happening. We have:

$$P(1) = \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{2}$$
$$P(2) = \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$
$$P(3) = \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}$$

We thus find:

$$P = \frac{P(1) + P(3)}{P(1) + P(2) + P(3)} = \frac{\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{12}}{\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{24} + \frac{1}{12}} = \frac{4 + 2}{4 + 1 + 2} = \frac{6}{7} \approx 0.857$$

Comment: How is P(4) possible if we do not repeat the staplers after already trying them?

Comment: @ThePoorJew A mistake on my part. Corrected!